# Aplication in background AvPlayer Radio Station

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an online Radio Station and when I close the application it stops working.
I've been searching about running in the background, but not found much.

```
 - (IBAction)Play:(id)sender {
    if (Clicked == 0) {
        Clicked = 1;
        NSString *url = @"http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        NSURL *urlStream = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        AudioPlay = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithURL:urlStream];
        [AudioPlay play];
        [start setTitle:@"Stop" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        [AudioPlay pause];
        [start setTitle:@"Start" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        Clicked = 0;
    }
}
```

Thank

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When I lock or close the application has stopped working ... I want the application to be running in the background.

Comment: Fabricio...did you look at my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at iOS [`UIBackgroundModes`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22)

There is a background mode for `audio` which you simply declare in your `Info.plist`:

> audio: The app plays audible content in the background.

This is what it would look like in your .plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
        <string>audio</string>
</array>
```